# Dedicated Instances with docker-machine amazon aws driver

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-machine

Is there a way to create an AWS dedicated instance with the docker-machine driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need use your AMI with installed docker daemon.
Or user RHeT AMI. Docker preinstalled there.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html